# “exponential function converts addition to multiplication” from Wikipedia

Tags: inequality

In [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), it says: "Intuitively this corresponds to the fact that the exponential function, which converts addition to multiplication, is strictly convex ...".

How is this meant?

Comment: Which part/word do you fail to understand in this statement?

Comment: A convex function satisfies $ f\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right) \le \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2} $. That's the important part of the exponential function being convex. Then replace $ f $ with $ exp $ and use a bit of arithmetic to conclude.

Comment: How does the exponential function "convert" addition to multiplication?

Answer (score 4):

Let $\exp$ denote the exponential function. Then
$$\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\cdot\exp(b).$$
In fancier language, $\exp$ is a [*group homomorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism) from the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ under addition, to the positive real numbers $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ under multiplication.